# Azure app insights - ApiKey shows in logs (verbose)

Tags: azure

During azure function implementation and logging somehow logs shows ApiKey from request header during post to external api.which is security vulnerability.
How to hide ApiKey from trace.

```
LoggingLevel under appsettings is set to warning ( not information)
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning",
      "System": "Warning",
      "Microsoft": "Warning"
    }
```

***Traces***

[image]

Tried setting logging level to warning.

Answer (score 0):

The `requestTelemetry.Properties` are populated by the `Application Insights`.

The SDK captures the HTTP headers of the incoming request and stores them in the `requestTelemetry.Properties`

I used the below code to not to show the API keys in logs.

```
public class HideKeys:ITelemetryInitializer
    {
        public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
        {
            if (telemetry is RequestTelemetry requestTelemetry)
            {
                if (requestTelemetry.Properties.ContainsKey("API key"))
                {
                    requestTelemetry.Properties.Remove("API key");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    enter code here
```

StartUp code

```
 public class Startup : FunctionStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<ITelemetryInitializer, HideKeys>();
        }
    }
    enter code here
```

[image]

[image]